# Debug React App running behind a nginx proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, nginx, webstorm

I have a react app that is running on `localhost:3000`. And my Backend API is running on `localhost:8181`. In order to remove cross-origin requests, and some other compatibility reasons, I set up an nginx reverse proxy for my react app and my backend API. They now both run on `localhost:8443`.

The Problem: When I create a JavaScript debug configuration in Webstorm for `localhost:3000` it works fine. But a configuration for `localhost:8443` is not able to debug my react app. I cannot debug on `localhost:3000` because I do not get data from the API there.

I can debug using the `console.log()` but it would be really nice to have it debug in the IDE itself. I tried searching for a solution but did not find anything helpful for my configuration.

Any pointer to how I can enable  the debug for such a configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out the problem was my self-signed certificate. It had `localhost.com` as Common-Name instead of `localhost`.

Which can be found out by looking for `(java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found)` exception in WebStorm logs.
([How to find Log files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files))

I created a new certificate. This time with Common-Name as `localhost` and the debugging works!

Here is the link to the origianl issue that I opened on Youtrack for Webstorm support. ([Link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34490))

Hope this helps someone in the future!